# Checking for out of bounds in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to check the neighboring values of each element in a 2D array but am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I reach the sides of the array or a corner. For example if my array is:

### |2|4|2|7|8|

### |8|1|0|5|6|

### |0|3|1|5|2|

### |1|9|7|2|0|

I know that all the neighbors of 8 are  7,5 and 6, but my `if` statements don't check the bounds properly. The code I have for this is:

```
 int numOfRows = imageArray.length;
 int numOfColumns = imageArray[0].length;

 for(int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < numOfColumns; j++)

       if((j+1) < numOfColumns-1)

       if((i+1) < numOfRows-1)

       if((j-1) > 0 )

       if((i-1) > 0 )

       if((i+1) < numOfColumns-1 && (j+1) < numOfRows-1)

       if((i-1) >= 0 && (j-1) >= 0)

       if((i+1) < numOfColumns-1 && (j-1) >= 0)

       if((i-1) >= 0 && (j+1) < numOfRows-1)
```

I've been working on this for a while and have gone through many different techniques to solve this. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `if((j+1)` will exceed the bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to get all the neighbor cells and do something with them, for example add them, then you need to do some sort of bounds checking, for example something modified from this could work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numOfCols; j++) {
        // check all bounds out of range:
        int iMin = Math.max(0, i - 1);
        int iMax = Math.min(numOfRows - 1, i + 1);
        int jMin = Math.max(0, j - 1);
        int jMax = Math.min(numOfCols - 1, j + 1);

        // loop through the above numbers safely
        for (int innerI = iMin; innerI <= iMax; innerI++) {
            for (int innerJ = jMin; innerJ <= jMax; innerJ++) {
                if (i != innerI && j != innerJ) {
                    // do what needs to be done
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Caveat: code has not been compiled nor tested and is mainly to show you the idea of what can be done rather than a copy-paste solution